# How do I query revision history in ArangoDB?

Tags: graph-databases, arangodb, aql, nosql

I see the `_rev` in every document created in ArangoDB, but I have yet to see any information about using those revisions to access the change history for a document. More specifically, how do I query the revision history for a specific document to see the previous versions or even a specific version in time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My understanding is that the revision (`_rev`) attribute is just there as a marker so you can know when a field was updated. You can't change it directly, but every time you `UPDATE` a document in a collection, the `_rev` value is updated.

To store historical values you would need to implement a process to archive the old values of a document when they get updated.

The `_rev` attribute can be very helpful when scanning a document and seeing if any values were changed. Rather than having to do a deep compare on a document and what you expect to see, you can just compare the `_rev` attribute with what you expect to see. If the database returns a different `_rev` value than what you were checking for then your code can respond to the document changing, however required.

Remember, you have access to the old version of a document when you execute an `UPDATE` or `UPSERT` command ([the doco](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.0/AQL/Operations/Update.html)) and you could choose to return the `OLD` document contents to push off to an archive location, or process as you wish. The updated document will receive a new `_rev` value after that update.

The `OLD` value does not persist after the return of the `UPDATE` or `UPSERT` command, so you'll have to archive it right away or the older document will be lost.